# Java рекурсия , задача на сообразительность

Tags: java, массивы, рекурсия

Привет всем . Решаю одну задачу и не могу решить. Нужна помощь.
И так:

Есть двухмерный массив. Надо найти самый короткий путь от (0,0) До правого нижнего конца например (4,4). Путь через [1,1][2,2] и так далее запрещен.диагональный путь запрещен.в конце должен вывести самый короткий путь.в нашем случае выведет "10".Извините, я не знаю как вам перевести вопрос с фотографии.и хватит ставить минусы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наработки:

```
public class moed2AQuation12015
```

{

```
public static void main (String args[]){ 
    int mat [][] =  {{ 3,13,15,28,30},
                    { 40,51,52,29,30},
                    { 28,10,53,54,53},
                    { 53,12,55,53,60},
                    { 70,62,56,20,80},
                    { 80,81,90,95,100}};
    System.out.println(" " + shortestPath(mat));
}

public static int shortestPath (int [][] mat){
    return shortestPath (mat,0,0,0,0,1);
}
public static int shortestPath (int [][] mat,int x,int y,int x1, int y1,int count){
    x1 = mat.length -1;
    y1 = mat[0].length -1;
    if (x > x1 || y > y1) return 0;
    if ( x == mat.length && y == mat[0].length ) return 1;
    System.out.println(" -> " + mat[x][y] + " --> " + count);
    count = shortestPath(mat,x+1,y,x1,y1,count +1) + shortestPath(mat,x,y+1,x1,y1,count +1);
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: А можно полное условие? В таком виде все сильно просто, в общем случае это решается поиском в ширину...

Comment: Ответ хороший. Но не это от меня хотят на экзамене. Если я напишу : arr.length +arr[0].length -1 ... Тогда получу 5 баллов из 25.

Comment: @YosefGorbov: Мне кажется, вы считаете, будто мы должны написать вам ответ в таком виде, чтобы он понравился вашему преподавателю.

Comment: Нет, дать решения на все случаи.

Comment: Я уже нашел. Всем большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class pathFinder
{
 public static void main (String args[]){
    int mat [][] = {{ 3,13,15,28,30},
                    { 40,51,52,29,30},
                    { 28,10,53,54,53},
                    { 53,12,55,53,60}, 
                    { 70,62,56,20,80}, 
                    { 80,81,90,95,100}};
    System.out.println (shorterPath(mat)); 
} 

public static int shorterPath(int[][]mat)
{
    return shorterPath(mat,0,0,0,0);
}

public static int shorterPath(int[][]mat,int i,int j,int counter,int preval)
{
    if(!isValid(mat,i,j)|| preval >= mat[i][j])
        return mat.length*mat[0].length*2;

    if (i==mat.length-1 && j== mat[0].length-1)
    {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }

    else
    {
        int a=shorterPath(mat,i+1,j,counter+1,mat[i][j]);
        int b=shorterPath(mat,i-1,j,counter+1,mat[i][j]);
        int c=shorterPath(mat,i,j+1,counter+1,mat[i][j]);
        int d=shorterPath(mat,i,j-1,counter+1,mat[i][j]);

        if(a<=b && a<=c && a<=d)
            return a;
        if(b<=a && b<=c && b<=d)
            return b;
        if(c<=a && c<=b && c<=d)
            return c;
        return d;
    }

}


public static boolean isValid(int[][]a,int i,int j)
{
    if(i>=0 && i<=a.length-1 && j>=0 && j<= a[0].length-1)
    return true;
    else return false;
}
```

}